# mp3 does not loop after set as ringtone

Tags: android, loops, mp3, ringtone, ogg

I am writing a soundboard application for Android and I'm currently using mp3s. After setting them as ringtone they are played only once and won't loop. Apparently most people just convert them to ogg and set the ANDROID_LOOP flag, which helped (like [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1165708)).

Is this the only way, or is it also somehow possible to make mp3s loop (when set as ringtone)?

Comment: Easiest way I have found is to get an editor copy and paste the same mp3 several times in the same file and generate about 1.5 seconds of silence in between each insert.